# Survivor distribution following a zombie outbreak

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose there is initially a population of $A$ humans and $B$ zombies. You are sitting on a nearby hill with a shotgun; however, you're not a very good shot, so each time you pull the trigger, one of the members of the population is hit uniformly at random.

- If you hit a zombie, the zombie dies.
- If you hit a human, the zombies pile onto the poor wounded human and turn them into a new zombie.

Undeterred by your lack of skill, you continue to take shots into the population until there are no more zombies. At this point, what can be said about the distribution of the number of human survivors?

For example, we can try to compute the probability $q(A,B)$ that there are no survivors at the end of the process. This quantity should satisfy the recurrence $$q(A,B) = \frac{A}{A+B} q(A-1, B+1) + \frac{B}{A+B} q(A, B-1)$$ with the initial conditions $q(0,k) = 1$ for $k\ge 0$ and $q(k,0) = 0$ for $k>0$. Is there a simple formula for $q(A,B)$ or reasonable asymptotics? What can be said about the probability $q(k,A,B)$ that there are $k$ survivors for $1\le k \le A$?

Also, looking at some data seems to suggest that we always have a "reverse unimodal" property $$q(0,A,B) > q(1,A,B) > \cdots < q(A-1, A, B) < q(A, A, B)$$ with $q(0,A, B) > q(A, A, B)$, i.e. it is likeliest to have zero survivors. Is it possible to show this in general?

Comment: does this formula cover the $k=0$ case?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, I actually made a mistake, as my $k$ in the RHS of the stated formula actually corresponds to the number of killed healthy people. So, it is more like $$ q(A-k, A, B) = \frac{A!B!}{(A+B)!}\sum_{\substack{1\leq i_1 \leq b \\ 1\leq i_2 \leq i_1+1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\leq i_k\leq i_{k-1}+1}} \prod_{p=1}^{k} \frac{i_p + 1}{a+i_p+1-p}. $$ This formula holds for $k = 1, \cdots, a$. When $k = 0$, i.e., no healthy people is killed, we simply have $$q(A, A, B) = \frac{A!B!}{(A+B)!}.$$

Comment: The $k=0$ formula doesn't satisfy the recurrence given by the OP. Your formula is seemingly close to the answer but there must be a mistake there, no?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, OP's recurrence relation is for $q(A, B) = q(0, A, B)$. This has nothing to do with the quantity $q(A, A, B) = A!B!/(A+B)!$.

Comment: It is the same recurrence as the OP's, just with different boundary conditions, according to the answer below.  Am I not seeing something?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, Aha, now I see what you are mentioning. Plugging $k=A$ to the recurrence relation, we get $$q(A,A,B)=\frac{B}{A+B}q(A,A,B-1),$$where we utilized the obvious fact that $q(A,A-1,B+1)=0$ This recurrence relation I'd satisfied with $A!B!/(A+B)!$.

Comment: Sorry for the persistence, what do
 $a,b$ stand for in the above formula?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg, Nice catch to another typo. As you may suspect, they are simply $A$ and $B$ written in lowercase. I failed to change idiosyncratic notations to those of OP's.

Comment: @SangchulLee - your comments are intriguing but I also find them a little confusing.  Do you mind writing an Answer and defining everything clearly in it, including notation and how you got the big summation formula?

Comment: @antkam, The summation formula is rather straightforward as it is just the sum of probabilities over all possible paths beginning from $(A, B)$ and landing at $(A-k, 0)$. Each path is parametrized by the moments $(A, i_1), (A-1, i_2), \cdots, (A-k+1, i_k)$ at which the shooter hit a human. Perhaps it may find some uses for finding asymptotic forms of survival probabilities, although I haven't thought about it.

Comment: Also, I highly suspect that $q(A, B)\approx0$ for large $A$ and $B$, based on the observation that the typical trajectory started at $(n\alpha, n\beta)$, when scaled by $1/n$ will converge a.s. to a deterministic path starting from $(\alpha, \beta)$ and ends at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, based on the simulations I've looked at, it seems $q(A,B)$ is quite large for large $A$, $B$ and is perhaps approaching $1$. This seems to match the intuition that each time a human is zombified, it becomes more likely that more humans will become zombified in the future. Am I misunderstanding something/perhaps I haven't looked at large enough $A$, $B$?

Comment: @SameerKailasa, I again made a stupid mistake, where what I really wanted to say was that there are no survivor in high probability. (Which is implied by the claim that the typical trajectory will hit $(0, 0)$.) So you are right, we expect that $q(A, B) \approx 1$ for large $A$ and $B$. I am not sure why I keep making mistakes in stating my intentions... :s

Answer (score 2):

Possible approach / too long for a comment

Your recurrence for no survivors can be easily generalized to a recurrence for $k$ survivors.  Let $q(k,A,B)$ be the probability of ending with $k$ survivors starting with $A$ humans and $B$ zombies.  Then:

$$q(k,A,B) = \frac{A}{A+B}\, q(k,A-1, B+1) + \frac{B}{A+B}\, q(k,A, B-1)$$

In other words, the "form" of the equation is identical regardless of $k$, and that's because the recurrence is ultimately just based on the Law of Total Probability, applied to the event "$k$ survivors".

The boundary conditions however depend on $k$:
$$
q(k, A, 0) = \left. \begin{cases}
1, & k = A\\
0, & k \ne A
\end{cases}\right\|
 = \mathbb{I}_{\{k=A\}}.
$$

IMHO there is no real need to specify any boundary cases when $B>0$.  By definition you will keep shooting until $B=0$ anyway, and therefore reach some $q(k, A,0)$ state.  (Of course, for actual numerical calculations, it makes sense to specify $q(k, A, B) = 0$ whenever $A < k$ just to save computations.)

*Wild guess:* Since the "form" of the recurrence does not depend on $k$, and the boundary conditions contain only a single dot with non-zero value, I feel vaguely hopeful that there might be further simplifications available, e.g. by "back propagating" out from that single non-zero dot.  However, that's just a very vague gut feel, and even if it pans out, I would be surprised if the solution isn't a complicated summation and/or product form.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.* I think I can prove the following rather technical claim about the behavior of the zombie apocalypse started with large population.

Fix $\alpha, \beta > 0$. Then starting from the initial condition $(\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor, \lfloor \beta n \rfloor)$, denote by $(A_n, B_n)$ the pair of numbers of survivors/zombies after the $n$-th shot. If $T$ is the first time $n$ at which $B_n = 0$, then we consider the path $(Z_t)_{0 \leq t \leq T/n}$ defined by

$$ Z_t = \tfrac{1 - (nt - \lfloor nt \rfloor)}{n}(A_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}, B_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}) + \tfrac{nt - \lfloor nt \rfloor}{n}(A_{\lfloor nt \rfloor+1}, B_{\lfloor nt \rfloor+1}). $$

In other words, $(Z_t)$ is the piecewise linear path joining points $\frac{1}{n}(A_k, B_k)$'s and the speed is chosen so that each line segment from $\frac{1}{n}(A_k, B_k)$ to $\frac{1}{n}(A_{k+1}, B_{k+1})$ is traced at a uniform speed within the time interval $[k/n, (k+1)/n]$. Then

> **Technical Claim.** As $n\to\infty$, $(Z_t)_{0 \leq t \leq T/n}$ converges in distribution to a deterministic curve $\gamma = (\gamma(t))_{0 \leq t \leq 2\alpha+\beta}$. Moreover, $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ satisfies
>   $$ x' = -\frac{x}{x+y}, \qquad y' = \frac{x-y}{x+y}, \qquad (x(0), y(0)) = (\alpha, \beta). $$
>   Here, two paths on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are close if their graphs in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are close in Hausdorff distance.

Loosely speaking, the piecewise linear path joining $(A_n, B_n)$'s are close to the curve

$$ \frac{y}{x} + \log x = \text{constant}. $$

The following plot demonstrates this phenomenon in the case of $(a, b) = (1000, 500)$. The black line represents the curve $y/x + \log x = \text{const}$, where the constant is chosen so that it passes through $(a, b)$. Also, the colored zigzag curves represent 10 simulations of the history of zombie apocalypse.

[image: Simulation 1]

Now, doing the same simulation with $(a, b) = (10000, 5000)$,

[image: Simulation 2]

We clearly see concentration behavior emerges.

Comment: very cool plots!  but what do you mean by "any history ... pairs up to extinction, scaled by $1/n$"?  also, can you explain how you come up with the formula $y/x + \log x = $ constant?  did you derive that through some approximation via (continuous) differential equations?

Comment: @antkam, A heuristic explanation is that, if $A$ is the number of humans and $B$ is the number of zombies, then after a shot, the expected number of humans and zombies change by $\Delta A$ and $\Delta B$, where $$\Delta A -\frac{A}{A+B},\qquad\Delta B=\frac{A-B}{A+B}.$$ From this, we get $\Delta B/\Delta A=-1+(B/A)$, and so, it is reasonable to look at the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-1+\frac{y}{x}.$$ The solution of this equation satisfies the relation $(y/x) + \log x=\text{constant}$. Of course, there are more rigorous explanation as to why we expect this curve to occur.